# Issue with Google Analytics

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics

We have extention less urls for our web site. 
Here for example "somepage.aspx" is one of our page...so if some type in address bar and  hits "somepage" then request goes to "somepage.aspx"..
We have GA tracking enable for our websites.
In google analytics, we get the different count for this page even the page is same in both cases. I want to track the count under only  one page.
Now i am getting tracking result as follows

Page Name     || count

Somepage.aspx || 5

Somepage      || 10

but  I want result like this 
Page Name || count
Somepage.aspx || 15

Please help me out...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 301 redirect on .aspx to redirect it to extension less or implement link of canonical url like shown [Adding the CANONICAL tag to my page for SEO through code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398821/adding-the-canonical-tag-to-my-page-for-seo-through-code-behind)

Comment: Thanks Prashant for your reply... Tommarow Morning I will try and will let you know...